# Entity Framework update in disconnected mode

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to update an entity Order using an object (i.e. order) which is sent from the UI.

I have the following in my method

```
Order neworder = new Order
        {
            ID = order.ID,
            FirstName = order.FirstName,
            LastName = order.LastName,
        };
        _bentities.Order.ApplyCurrentValues(neworder);

        _bentities.SaveChanges();
```

This works fine if I fill all the non-nullable values of entity Order. However I have only got few properties which are modified. I just want to update these modified properties (not all the non-nullable values which are not modified)

How can I do it?

I have read I can set the modified properties as:

```
var entry = _bentities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)neworder).EntityKey);
        entry.SetModifiedProperty("FirstName");
        entry.SetModifiedProperty("LastName");
```

However this does not work for some reason. I get an exception that EntityKey cannot be null. How do I set the entitykey for neworder and then will this work?

Comment: you might want to see this post for your answer.

[See here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257360/how-to-update-not-every-fields-of-an-object-using-entity-framework-and-entitysta)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *update* and entity, you'd have to fetch it from database first, and then call `ApplkyCurrentValues`.

```
order originalOrder = _bentities.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.ID == updatedOrder.ID);
_bentities.Orders.ApplyCurrentValues(updatedOrder);
```