# How to Update only single field using EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

This is the current basic code :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Registration registration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(registration);
    }
```

I have around 15 fields in Registration table , how ever i just want to update the "Date" field , the object that i receive here is "registration" which only has value for a date , but the current code updates all the entries , what i want is to just update the "Date" field , whose value i have got in "registration"

Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

Attach it to the context in the `Unchanged` state, and only set `Date` as modified.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Registrations.Attach(registration); // attach in the Unchanged state
    db.Entry(registration).Property(r => r.Date).IsModified = true;
    // Date field is set to Modified (entity is now Modified as well)
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

You said the incoming entity only has `Date` filled in, hopefully there's an Id too. :)

Comment: yes there is an id , is .Attach a method tht comes with EF? or it has to be made? coz db.Attach(registration); is giving error saying that this method needs to be created

Comment: Sorry, the `Attach()` method is on the `DbSet` itself. Corrected.

Comment: Thanx a bunch :)
mission accomplished :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(registration).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(registration).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = false; //Add fields which you don't want to modify
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Update :** as per answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257360/how-to-update-not-every-fields-of-an-object-using-entity-framework-and-entitysta)

```
var excluded = new[] { "property1", "property2" };
var entry = context.Entry(obj);
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach (var name in excluded)
{
    entry.Property(name).IsModified = false;
}
```

Comment: according to this i'll have to manually exclude a number of records , like around 14 , cant i just mention one property that i have to update? something like below :

UPDATE dbo.registrations SET Date = registration WHERE id = registrations.id -- i don't care about the other fields

Answer (score 1):

```
Registration registor =db.Registration.First(f=>RegistrationId==RegistrationId);
registor.Date = registration.Date;
db.SaveChanges();
```

use this for single record updation and i assuming that RegistrationId in your Registration table.